# How to check an item is present visually in webgl

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am working on threejs, I had encountered a problem regarding it i.e.
In my project people has many items which can be added, so the problem is regarding testing how can i check if an item is added by user is displayed to user or not i.e. it is visible on screen or not.
Is there any automatic way to check that

Comment: reword your question as it is hard to understand what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve this is using a frustum to ray cast on items added in the scene, Your best approach is for every item added to the screen should be also pushed in to an array, you could use this array to check on an event if an item is with-in the frustum of the camera (your view in scene).

Check out raycasting docs.

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Raycaster

[image]